# Why doesn't Perl6 check the array length after append?

Tags: types, raku

I've defined a new type `Tuple` as follows:

```
subset Tuple of Array where { .elems == 2 && .[0] < .[1] };
my Tuple $t = [1, 2];
say $t;  # [1 2] So far, so good.
```

I can't initialize it with shorter or longer array or with `[2, 1]`, as expected. But, I can append to it:

```
$t.append(3);
say $t;  # [1 2 3] Ouch!
```

How's that possible?

Answer (score 6):

`my Tuple $t` creates a `$t` variable such that any (re)assignment or (re)binding to it must (re)pass the `Tuple` type check.

`= [1, 2]` assigns a reference to an `Array` object. The `Tuple` type check is applied (and passes).

`$t.append(3)` modifies the contents of the `Array` object held in `$t` but does not reassign or rebind `$t` so there's no type check.

Mutating-method-call syntax -- `$t.=append(3)` instead of `$t.append(3)` -- will trigger the type check on `$t`.

There is specific syntax for a bounds-checked array (`my @array[2]` etc.) but I'm guessing that's not the point of your question.

Answer (score 4):

The type constraint is bound to the scalar container, but the object it contains is just a plain old array - and an array's `append` method is unaware you want it to trigger a type check.

If you want to explicitly trigger the check again, you could do a reassignment like `$t = $t`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an altered version of an [`Array`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Array), you can simply create a class that inherits from it and overrides the methods that you want to behave differently. (There are probably much more elegant ways to do this, but this does work):

```
class Tuple is Array {
    method append ( *@val ) {
        fail '"append" is disabled for Tuples'
    }
}

my $t = Tuple.new(1,2);

say $t;

$t.append(3);
```

Then it will work like you expect:

```
[1 2]
"append" is disabled for Tuples
  in method append at example.p6 line 2
  in block <unit> at example.p6 line 11

Actually thrown at:
  in block <unit> at example.p6 line 11
```

Alternately, to get something similar you could use a dimensioned array [as mentioned by raiph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951074/215487). Or, if you simply want something immutable that is similar to an array, you can then use a [`List`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List).